# Need source for elliptic regularity on unbounded domains

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

> I need a source that provides a $W^{2,2}$-regularity result for linear elliptic systems on unbounded domains.

- To be more specific, I study the equation $$ -\Delta w - ic \partial_1 w + \left( \frac{c^2}{2}+2 \right)w = h ~~~ \mbox{on}~ \Omega $$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is some unbounded domain, $h$ is $L^2(\Omega, \mathbb{C})$, $w : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ and $c \in [0,\sqrt{2}]$. I want to show that if $w$ solves the above equation, then $w \in W^{2,2}(\Omega, \mathbb{C})$.
- Please note again: $\Omega$ is unbounded and by identifying $\mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$ we can regard $w$ as vector valued (and thus the equation is a  linear elliptic system). I.e. $w : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $h \in L^2(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^2)$.
- [This paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://www.math.polytechnique.fr/~gravejat/Recherch/GP-Limit.pdf&ei=LZlCUrRXxYHgBIPogfAM&usg=AFQjCNFq6Dnukvd23l1L8gX3j5kI7-3s-A&bvm=bv.53077864,d.bGE) suggests that this is an easy step (page 3), but I can't seem to find a source. Also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461089/need-help-understanding-this-proof-of-regularity-of-traveling-wave-solutions-to) to one of my earlier questions states the same thing, but does not provide a source either (and I did not ask for one back then).
- All sources I *can* find (e.g. [Giaquinta](http://books.google.de/books?id=NRmrMwEACAAJ&dq=giaquinta%20introduction%20to%20regularity&hl=de&sa=X&ei=CJpCUq-ZIYeX1AXkyIHIDg&redir_esc=y), [Taylor](http://books.google.de/books/about/Partial_Differential_Equations.html?id=vISPd8QJfHoC&redir_esc=y), [Gilbarg+Trudinger](http://books.google.de/books?id=eoiGTf4cmhwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=gilbarg%20trudinger&hl=de&sa=X&ei=h5pCUt7xA8K80QXg3IHYBA&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAA)) either don't talk about systems or treat them on bounded domains.

*Any* hint is much appreaciated!

Comment: I removed the regularity tag as that term is really ambiguous: in different contexts and different subjects, regularity can mean very different things. (Think algebraic geometry, statistics, and set theory for some different notions than PDEs.)

Comment: Is $c$ a scalar? Is it real? Or are they matrices? Are they constants? What are the boundary conditions? Have you tried just "norm-squaring" both sides and check coercivity on the left?

Comment: @WillieWong Sorry, I will add information about $c$. If I check for coercivity, I will still need a regularity result, don't I? Something like: If the left hand side is coercive, then...

Comment: @WillieWong And thanks for removing the tag! I did not think about this ambiguity.

Comment: Hum, at once you say that $w\in 
W^{2,2}(\Omega,\mathbb{R}^n)$ yet also require that it be complex valued. Do you mean that $w:\Omega\to \mathbb{C}^n$ instead? Similarly for $h$ perhaps? If $w$ and $h$ were real valued the regularity result is simple: just multiple both sides by Hermitian conjugates of their formula. The only cross term remaining is of the form $-\triangle w \cdot w$ which when you integrate by parts becomes positive.

Comment: @WillieWong Sorry, what I mean is splitting the system in a real and imaginary part, i.e. identifying $\mathbb{C} \simeq \mathbb{R}^2$. I should have made that clear and I will edit the post now. Thanks for your suggestion, but I still do not understand the rest of your comment... how exactly does that give me regularity?

Comment: Don't split. That's silly. Just multiply by hermitian conjugate. I'm sketching out the argument below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume we have good boundary behaviour (at the boundary $\partial \Omega$ and at $\infty$) so I can freely integrate by parts.

Consider
$$ \begin{align}
|h|^2 &= \left| - \Delta w - i c \partial_1 w + \left( \frac{c^2}{2} + 2\right) w \right| ^2 \\
& = \left| \Delta w \right|^2 + \left| c \partial_1 w \right|^2 + \left| \left( \frac{c^2}{2} + 2\right) w\right|^2 + 2 \Im \left[ c \Delta w \partial_1 \bar{w} - c \left( \frac{c^2}{2} + 2 \right) w \partial_1 \bar{w} \right] - 2 \Re \left[\Delta w \left( \frac{c^2}{2} + 2 \right) \bar{w} \right]
\end{align} $$

Integrating over $\Omega$, and integrating the last term by parts, we have (the norm $\|\cdot\|_k = \|\cdot\|_{W^{k,2}}$)

$$ \|h\|_{0}^2 = \|\Delta w\|^2_0 + c^2 \|\partial_1 w\|^2_0 + \left(\frac{c^2}{2} + 2\right)^2 \|w\|^2_0 + 2 \left( \frac{c^2}{2} + 2\right) \|\nabla w\|^2_0 + 2 c\int \Im \ldots $$

where the

$$ \ldots = \Delta w \partial_1 \bar{w} - \left( \frac{c^2}{2} + 2\right) w \partial_1 \bar{w} $$

Putting the imaginary parts into absolute values we have

$$ \|h\|_{0}^2 \geq \|\Delta w\|^2_0 + c^2 \|\partial_1 w\|^2_0 + \left(\frac{c^2}{2} + 2\right)^2 \|w\|^2_0 + 2 \left( \frac{c^2}{2} + 2\right) \|\nabla w\|^2_0 - 2 c \left| \int \Im \ldots \right| \tag{*}$$

Now we Cauchy-Schwarz the $\ldots$ with weights. We have that

$$ 2c\left| \int\Im\ldots \right| \leq  A \|\triangle w\|^2_0 + (A^{-1} + B^{-1})c^2 \|\partial_1 w\|^2_0 + B\left(\frac{c^2}{2} + 2\right)^2\|w\|^2_0 $$

for any positive real numbers $A,B$. It remains to choose good $A,B$.

But now we observe that $\|\nabla w\|^2_0 = \sum \|\partial_i w\|^2_0$ contains a factor of $\|\partial_1w\|^2_0$. We make use of that term.

Let us set $A = B = (1-\epsilon)$. Plugging in the estimate for the $\Im \ldots$ into (*) we get

$$ \|h\|^2_0 \geq \epsilon \|\Delta w\|^2_0 + \epsilon \left( \frac{c^2}{2} + 2\right) \|w\|^2_0 + \left(2 c^2 + 4 - \frac{2c^2}{1 - \epsilon}\right) \|\partial_1 w\|^2_0 + (c^2 + 4)\left( \|\partial_2 w\|^2_0 + \|\partial_3 w\|^2_0 \right) $$

Now we see that the right hand side $\geq C \|w\|^2_2$ for some constant $C$ which depends on the constant $c$, provided that we can choose $\epsilon$ depending on $c$ such that

$$ 2 c^2 \left(1 - \frac{1}{1-\epsilon}\right) + 4 > 0 $$

A little algebraic manipulation shows that this only requires

$$ \frac{2}{c^2} > \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon} $$

which can always be satisfied as $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon} = 0$. In the regime where $c^2 \in [0,2]$ as you supposed, the value $\epsilon = 1/4$ suffices for any such $c$.