# How exactly is the symbol of a differential operator connected to the regularity of its solutions?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

**Note:** I already asked a question about the very same differential operator [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504596/need-source-for-elliptic-regularity-on-unbounded-domains) and got a very nice answer, but this question is concerned with the connection of the symbol to the regularity. Unfortunately, my professor wants me to try this way.

---

- Consider the differential equation $$ -\Delta w - ic \partial_1 w + \left( \frac{c^2}{2}+2 \right) w = h ~~~ \mbox{on } \Omega, \tag{1}$$ where $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is some unbounded domain, $h \in L^2(\Omega,\mathbb{C})$, $w : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ and $c \in [0, \sqrt{2})$.
- According to [this](http://books.google.de/books?id=6AjuCoaL34AC&pg=PA79&dq=symbol%20linear%20operator&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pOFLUrOEJoTItAaTvoDQDA&redir_esc=y), the symbol of this differential operator is $$ \sigma(\xi)= \vert \xi\vert^2+c\xi_1+\left(\frac{c^2}{2}+2 \right) \geq 2 > 0.$$
- My professor told me that this implied that the operator is invertible and any weak solution to (1) is actually $H^2(\Omega)$ if $h$ is $L^2(\Omega)$.

> **Question:** Can anyone give me a hint on what the precise argumentation for the last point looks like or where I can find it?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is treated (in a more general setting) in the theory of *pseudodifferential operators*. If the symbol of a $k$-th order pseudodifferential operator is *elliptic* (for differential operators this is equivalent to the differential operator being elliptic), you get $W^{m+k,2}$ smoothness for the solution if the right side is in $W^{m,2}$, and also local invertibility.

The last chapter of Folland's *Introduction to partial differential equations* contains a quite readable introduction to the topic (Theorems 8.43 and 8.45 answer your question).

For unique solutions of boundary value problems or continuity of the inverse you don't get anywhere using symbols alone, as far as I know.